# How can I improve my photo of a night city landscape with a starry sky?

Tags: hdr, night-photography

I like taking city photographs, like monuments or squares, with a starry sky. Since the square/monument is usually well illuminated, I take advantage of HDR with a short exposure for the illuminated things and a long one for the sky. The final result has always some little problem I would like to avoid:

- the sky shot has flares I don't want: some areas have brighter "dark blue" and this results in an unaesthetic result, if not retouched
- I want to take as many stars as possible
- Noisy sky if I set high ISO, but more flares if I set a lower one (and more exposition time)

an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

What changes can I make in order to improve the points I've listed above?

Comment: Welcome to Photo SE; I've made a small tweak to this (good) question to stop it being _purely_ about changing settings, as there may be other things you can change which would improve things. Hope that's okay, if not feel free to revert my changes.

Comment: If you are taking pictures with a tripod you could take a second shot covering with a board the lower part of the picture and then stack the two frames.

Comment: @FluidCode good idea, I'll have a try

Comment: (Where was that photo taken?)

Comment: in Madrid, it's the Debod Temple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Debod

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't add too many stars. The amount of stars looks pretty reasonable to me given the lighting of the sky. If I were to see the whole milky way in your picture, my mind would go "yet another photoshop act".

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Templo_de_Debod,_2016_(01).jpg, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Templo_de_Debod,_2016_(02).jpg, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Templo_de_Debod,_2016_(03).jpg

Comment: What about a graduated nd filter? Might work for you

Comment: What was the ambient temperature when you took this photo? What was the dewpoint? Was there a lot of dust in the air?

Answer (score 14):

Your basic problem is that most stars are much dimmer than the parts of your scene lit up by artificial lighting. Combined with the diffusing properties of air and all of the particulates and moisture floating around in it, there is a haze from the  brighter light reflecting off the stuff in the air and it is drowning out the very dim light from all except the brightest stars or planets.

Since you can't increase the amount of light provided by the stars, your only option to balance the two is to reduce the brightness of the artificial illumination in the scene. Is there a time later at night when the flood lights are turned off and you can shoot the scene while only illuminating the monuments and buildings using techniques such as light painting or controlled flashes. The advantage to either one is that the stars can be exposed for longer while the light you provide for the foreground subjects can be much shorter in duration.

The only other option if you want a darker sky with stars showing in it is to shoot a separate frame for the sky away from the light pollution of the artificial lighting and combine the two shots after the fact. HDR won't really give optimal results in this case because it will pull up the very dim diffused light that is reflected off the moisture, dust, and other particulates in the air along with the stars and that diffused light will continue to limit how many stars are bright enough to shine through the haze.

Comment: I think a sodium line filter for the star shot may also help in some situations, though sodium lamps are disappearing and don’t seem to dominate the example scene.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the existing answers to try fix it at source, another option is to use something like Aurora HDR, which you can use on your separate shots or even the composite. The closer to the original RAW files you give it, though, the more it can work it.

This is what I managed to squeeze out of it using your uploaded jpg.
I added a little bit of burn & dodge in Photoshop.
Not brilliant, but not too shabby…

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

The warm glow we'll call artistic interpretation ;) I couldn't really get any detail back into the trees , but I managed to rescue a fair bit back into the stonework. From the RAW I'd bet you can get a lot more out of the stars too.